# Why did the Japanese allow the prisoners to stop working and watch Louis' game?

Tags: plot-explanation, unbroken

In one scene in [**Unbroken**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1809398/), the prisoners should be carrying coal, but they stop and watch Louis' game.

[image]

Actually the Japanese conducted the game on Louis, if he drops the log he is carrying then they will shoot him.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Japanese are the ones running the game, a game that involves shooting the looser,  it's not a game, it's a punishment or lesson. They let the rest watch so they learn that either you do what you are told, or you will be killed.

Public humiliation and punishments are a common tactic in keeping prisoners demoralized and compliant.